# R Shiny: uiOutput takes too long to appear after start while data is loading

Tags: r, shiny

I am using uiOutput to create a fileInput widget on server side, so that it is resettable. My problem now is, that the server side takes some time to load data which makes the widget appear later. Is there a solution for that? Some kind of "wait while loading"-text perhaps?

Here's a minimal example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('id_resettableupload'),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  # simulate data load
  Sys.sleep(5)
  
  # define file input widget
  output$id_resettableupload <- renderUI({
    fileInput(inputId = "ABC")
  })
  # reset
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    output$id_resettableupload <- renderUI({
      fileInput(inputId = "ABC")    
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and see if `shinycssloaders` is helpful in your case
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinycssloaders/index.html